# connection error to redshift within Apache Airflow

Tags: connection, amazon-redshift, airflow

I have installed Apache Airflow on Centos VMware, I have created a connection through Airflow UI to Redshift

**Admin** --> *connections*

When i run the adhoc query through **Data profiling** , i get the below error.

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused 
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
could not connect to server: Connection refused 
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Kindly let me know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says `Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?` which seems to indicate that you are trying to connect to Redshift running at `localhost:5432`, which is unlikely.

Though port `5432` is usually for postgres?

Maybe double check that you've configured your Redshift/postgres connection correctly?

Comment: i have setup my connection in Airlow for redshift with Port 5439 and my cluster endpoint as host, i am not sure why Airlow still looks for some thing running on 'localhost:5432'.